# Anybody able to use GitLab Maven Repository Group Level Endpoint?

Tags: maven, gitlab

I have a group on GitLab with two projects, and I wish to use the [group level maven endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html#group-level-maven-endpoint) so that each project can reference one repository URL for the group instead of each project needing to know the specific project repositories.

However, I cannot seem to get it to work.  I can build a library and push its artifact to the repository, and another project can find it with the [project level maven endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html#project-level-maven-endpoint).  However, when I use the group level repository URL as described in the document, replacing `my-group` with my group, the build fails because it "Could not find artifact".  Has anybody got this to work?

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/my-group/-/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody with the same problem, I was able to make it work with the group ID.

Comment: I'm getting "Failed to execute goal on project [Prj-B]: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.comp.core_sec:[Prj-B]:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.comp.core_lib:[Prj-A]:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<grp-id>/-/packages/maven) -> [Help 1] Can you post your resolution here. I'm using Trail Silver/premium account. Thankx